# Oracle Merge, not logging errors

Tags: oracle, merge, error-logging

I'm merging several tables in Oracle 10g, into a consolidated table, like this:

```
table_A (will have all the records)
table_b -part of the data to be merged
table_c -part of the data to be merged
table_d -part of the data to be merged
```

now, i run it with error logging like this

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_A A USING (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B) B
ON
(
A.NOMBRE=B.NOMBRE AND
A.PRIMER_APELLIDO=B.PRIMER_APELLIDO AND
A.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO=B.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO AND
TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_NACIMIENTO,'DD/MM/YYYY')=TO_CHAR(B.FECHA_NACIMIENTO,'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
A.SEXO=B.SEXO
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET DGP2011='1'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
A.FOLIO_RELACIONADO,
A.CVE_PROGRAMA,
A.FECHA_ALTA,
A.PRIMER_APELLIDO,
A.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
A.NOMBRE,
A.FECHA_NACIMIENTO,
A.SEXO,
A.CVE_NACIONALIDAD,
A.CVE_ENTIDAD_NACIMIENTO,
A.CVE_GRADO_ESCOLAR,
A.CVE_GRADO_ESTUDIOS,
A.CURP,
A.CALLE,
A.NUM_EXT,
A.NUM_INT,
A.CODIGO_POSTAL,
A.ENTRE_CALLE,
A.Y_CALLE,
A.OTRA_REFERENCIA,
A.TELEFONO,
A.COLONIA,
A.LOCALIDAD,
A.CVE_MUNICIPIO,
A.CVE_ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA,
A.CVE_CCT,
A.PRIMER_APELLIDO_C,
A.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO_C,
A.NOMBRE_C,
A.FECHA_NACIMIENTO_C,
A.SEXO_C,
A.CVE_ESTADO_CIVIL_C,
A.CVE_GRADO_ESTUDIOS_C,
A.CVE_PARENTESCO_C,
A.CURP_C,
A.CVE_TIPO_ID_OFCL_C,
A.ID_DOCTO_OFL_C,
A.CVE_NACIONALIDAD_C,
A.CVE_ENTIDAD_NACIMIENTO_C,
A.CALLE_C,
A.NUM_EXT_C,
A.NUM_INT_C,
A.CODIGO_POSTAL_C,
A.ENTRE_CALLE_C,
A.Y_CALLE_C,
A.OTRA_REFERENCIA_C,
A.TELEFONO_C,
A.COLONIA_C,
A.LOCALIDAD_C,
A.CVE_MUNICIPIO_C,
A.CVE_ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA_C,
A.E_MAIL_C,
A.DGP2011
)
VALUES
(
B.FOLIO_RELACIONADO,
B.CVE_PROGRAMA,
B.FECHA_ALTA,
B.PRIMER_APELLIDO,
B.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO,
B.NOMBRE,
TO_CHAR(B.FECHA_NACIMIENTO,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
B.SEXO,
B.CVE_NACIONALIDAD,
B.CVE_ENTIDAD_NACIMIENTO,
B.CVE_GRADO_ESCOLAR,
B.CVE_GRADO_ESTUDIOS,
B.CURP,
B.CALLE,
B.NUM_EXT,
B.NUM_INT,
B.CODIGO_POSTAL,
B.ENTRE_CALLE,
B.Y_CALLE,
B.OTRA_REFERENCIA,
B.TELEFONO,
B.COLONIA,
B.LOCALIDAD,
B.CVE_MUNICIPIO,
B.CVE_ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA,
B.CVE_CCT,
B.PRIMER_APELLIDO_C,
B.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO_C,
B.NOMBRE_C,
TO_CHAR(B.FECHA_NACIMIENTO_C,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
B.SEXO_C,
B.CVE_ESTADO_CIVIL_C,
B.CVE_GRADO_ESTUDIOS_C,
B.CVE_PARENTESCO_C,
B.CURP_C,
B.CVE_TIPO_ID_OFCL_C,
B.ID_DOCTO_OFL_C,
B.CVE_NACIONALIDAD_C,
B.CVE_ENTIDAD_NACIMIENTO_C,
B.CALLE_C,
B.NUM_EXT_C,
B.NUM_INT_C,
B.CODIGO_POSTAL_C,
B.ENTRE_CALLE_C,
B.Y_CALLE_C,
B.OTRA_REFERENCIA_C,
B.TELEFONO_C,
B.COLONIA_C,
B.LOCALIDAD_C,
B.CVE_MUNICIPIO_C,
B.CVE_ENTIDAD_FEDERATIVA_C,
B.E_MAIL_C,
'1'
)LOG ERRORS INTO ELOG_SEGURO_ESCOLAR REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

and it just raises the error "ORA-01722: invalid number" and toad highlights the 'A.' part of the query.

Now about the tables

```
table A has all the fields in varchar2 (4000)
table b to d have formatting according to the data they hold (date, number, etc)
```

the thing is, even with the error logging clause it raises the error and doesn't merge anything!

Plus i have no idea what i should be looking for to find the 'invalid number' field

Any advice would be deeply appreciated

Comment: Is the error coming from the `ON` clause? If so I don't think it would get as far as the error logging, which is for problems with the insert/update part. I'd look at the A columns in that clause first; are there `A.NOMBRE` values that are not really numbers, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

It was the `TO_CHAR(A.FECHA_NACIMIENTO,'DD/MM/YYYY')` line. Just left it like this
`A.FECHA_NACIMIENTO=B.FECHA_NACIMIENTO` and it worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: if you need to ignore any time part of your dates.. you can always use TRUNC() statements instead of doing the to_char()